# 'Comparison method violates its general contract' with no sign of transitive error

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparator, comparable

I have an abstract class, `CandidateProgram`, which implements the `Comparable` interface.

Within my code I have a List of its subclass, `GRCandidateProgram` which I sort via `Collections.sort`. When I sort I get the error "java.lang.illegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!"

The only answer I have found online is that this may be due to a transitive error in my `compareTo` method, however I do not think this is the case for my code. My `compareTo` method is as follows:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(final CandidateProgram o) {
    if (o == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("cannot compare to null");
    }

    final Double thisFitness = getFitness();

    return thisFitness.compareTo(o.getFitness());
}
```

Also of note: the error does not get thrown every time I sort, only sometimes though I cannot determine any rule as to which inputs trigger the error and which do not. For example, 50 instances of `GRCandidateProgram`, in a list with the following fitnesses appears to cause this error:

`3.0, 37.0, 70.0, 75.0, 80.0, 128.0, 161.0, 167.0, 172.0, 219.0, 253.0, 258.0, 263.0, 311.0, 344.0, 349.0, 355.0, 397.0, 402.0, 435.0, 441.0, 446.0, 488.0, 493.0, 527.0, 532.0, 537.0, 580.0, 585.0, 618.0, 624.0, 671.0, 676.0, 710.0, 715.0, 762.0, 768.0, 801.0, 806.0, 854.0, 859.0, 887.0, 892.0, 898.0, 945.0, 950.0, 971.0, 979.0, 984.0, 989.0`

Does anyone have any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: FWIW, the null check is not necessary--you'll get an NPE trying to dereference `o` anyway, at a pretty clear spot.

Comment: What is the declared type of `getFitness()`?

Comment: @chrylis : double (primitive type)

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're wrapping it instead of using the static compare method on `Double`?

Comment: What does `getFitness()` do? Can the result change?

Comment: @chrylis: There is no logical reason. I just tried an implementation using the Double `static' method and still received this error.

Comment: @shmosel : The fitness will run a test to measure execution time of an application. This inevitably has some variance so the result is _slightly_ different each time `getFitness()` is run.

Comment: We may need more code. Is there *any* chance that the list is concurrently modified during the sort?

Comment: Well, I assume there's your problem. If for one call `a.getFitness() > b.getFitness()` and for the next call `a.getFitness() < b.getFitness()`, the contract is broken. It'll help if you post your actual code.

Comment: @shmosel , thank you. It's very clear now that's the problem. I completely forgot that  about the variance in `getFitness`. I've just done a test run where I calculate the fitness once and cache it forever, everything appears to work fine

Comment: @chrylis : Thank you too, you were very helpful. Problem is now solved

Answer (score 0):

Answer was provided by @shmosel in the comments. `getFitness()` took real-world measurements and therefore returned a double value that could vary between calls. This breaks `Comparable`'s contract